# Prove that a multivariate density is valid

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

My question is quite simple. How to prove that a function $f(x_1,x_2,..., x_n)$ is a valid density? 
I mean, aside of the fact that must integrate to 1, and it must be positive, do i have to prove that all the marginals and conditionals exist or there exists a simple method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [Joint Probability Distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Joint_probability_distribution#/Continuous_case), you don't have to prove anything other than

- integration to 1
- non-negativity

If these conditions hold, your joint PDF is valid. And, all of your marginals also become automatically valid PDFs since:
$$\int{f(x_1)dx_1} = \int{\int{f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)dx_n...dx_1}} = 1$$

They'll also be non-negative since the integration of non-negative functions will be non-negative.